# How to create ServerControl using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, servercontrols

I want to create **dynamic Server controls(like text box and hidden field) in my project so that i can fetch their value at server side using JavaScript so that processing does not get slow** so I want to your suggestion that how can I perform this, 
Or **their is another approach which we can follow for this.**

Comment: you can use jquery ajax as an alternate approach.

Comment: Can you give  me any link which can explain this much better way

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36935/JavaScript-and-Server-Controls-101